# Replacement mouse for Bluetake BT500

Tags: mice

I have a Bluetooth [Bluetake BT500 mouse](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16826129101&cm_re=bluetake_bt500-_-26-129-101-_-Product) and one of the buttons is going (the left one of course), the case has some wear, and I'd like a comparable replacement.  It seems that the mouse is no longer in production, and I can't find a comparable replacement.  This mouse was a good match for a [UMPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultra-mobile_PC), so we're talking technology from almost 10 years ago.

My current mouse still mostly works, but if I can't repair the left mouse button switch, I'll need a replacement.

Is there a comparably small and well built Bluetooth mouse suitable to be a UMPC/Netbook/Tablet companion?

**Things I like(d) about the mouse:**

- Small
- Easy to pair
- Fit in a tacklebox (This happened to be dumb luck.  I often store gadgets in tackleboxes to secure them in transit)
- used AAA batteries (standard batteries)

**Things I dislike(d) about the mouse:**

- Used AAA batteries (I had to carry extra batteries)
- the battery cover latch got bent once and I could never get it quite right.  It was a hard plastic and I was worried about breaking it
- the left mouse button started to go flaky after a few months to a year of use

**New features that I might like to see**

- built in rechargeable battery
- built in battery can be swapped out for standard and/or replacement battery
- above battery would use a USB cable and also double as USB HID mouse
- comes with case
- especially durable
- presentation features (laser, forward, back, etc)
- not expensive (< $50)